# having a non-vanishing derivative is sufficient for a holomorphic function to be injective?

Tags: complex-analysis

If a holomorphic function is injective then its derivative is non-zero everywhere but is the reverse true?

Also for real functions, we know positive derivative corresponds to increasing function and negative corresponds to decreasing function, for holomorphic function can we draw conclusions on the behavior of the functions if the real part of the derivative is positive or if the derivative is purely imaginary, etc ...?
thanks

Comment: It will be locally injective but $\exp(z)$ shows that global injectivity needs further conditions.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3354390 for the second part of your question.

Answer (score 3):

The exponential function is periodic and thus not injective, but its derivative, the funcion itself, is vanishing nowhere.