# Prove $|\int_{\alpha} f(z) \ dz| \geq M|z-w|$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

I'm given a function $f: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. $f$ is holomorphic on $\Omega$. And we have $Re(f) \geq M > 0$. And $\alpha(t)$ connectes $z$ and $w$. Then I need to prove that $|\int_{\alpha} f(z)\ dz| \geq M|z-w|$. 
I first have $|\int_{\alpha} f(z)\ dz| \geq |\int_{\alpha} Re(f(z)) \ dz|$, since $|f(z)| \geq |Re(f(z))|$ according to the definition of module of complex numbers and Pythagorean Theorem. 
Then since $Re(f) \geq M$, then $|\int_{\alpha} Re(f(z)) \ dz| \geq |\int_{\alpha} M \ dz|$. 
Then since it's holomorphic, then it has primitive. 
Then according to the fundamental theorem of Calculus, we have $|\int_{\alpha} M \ dz| = |M(z-w)|= M|z-w|$, since $M > 0$. Thus we have $|\int_{\alpha} f(z) \ dz| > M|z-w|$ 
Can anyone tell if my proof is correct? Thank you!
 **EDIT** My instructor said he mistakenly put this wrong statement on the homework.

Comment: $dz$ is a complex measure so there are a few places where your proof is incorrect like when you claim that $|\int_{\alpha} f(z)\ dz| \geq |\int_{\alpha} Re(f(z)) \ dz|$; the result is not true in general unless $\alpha$ is the segment joining $z,w$ as there are counterexamples where $\Re f >M$ and there are two distinct points st $f(z)=f(w)$, though in that case the segment joining them is not in the domain

Comment: @Conrad So do I need to break it up like $\int_{a}^{b} f(\alpha (t)) \alpha ' (t) \ dt$. But if I break it up like this. Then I need to consider the additional term $\alpha ' (t)$ Then will the idea be basically the same, using Pythagorean Theorem?

Comment: @Conrad Is it true when the curve is smooth?

Comment: @Conrad Yeah I'm given that points $z$ and $w$ are connected via a smooth curve $\alpha$ inside $\Omega$. So I think that this corresponds to what you said? since it's inside the domain.

Comment: put an answer with a link to counterexamples when $\Omega$ is not convex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result is not true without extra assumptions, eg $\alpha$ is the segment joining $z,w$ or $\Omega$ convex.

There are many simply connected domains $\Omega$ that have points $w_0 \ne w_1$ and a holomorphic function with $\Re f \ge M>0$ st if $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$ we have $F(w_0)=F(w_1)$, so if we take any path $\alpha \subset \Omega$ connecting them, $\int_{\alpha} f(z)dz=\int_{\alpha} F'(z)dz=F(w_1)-F(w_0)=0$ so we definitely do not have $0=|\int_{\alpha} f(z)dz| \ge M|w_0-w_1|>0$

For examples of such see [my answer to a previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3354390/positive-real-part-of-derivative-imply-injectivity/3354444#3354444).