Making a holomorphic function injective on the unit disk by placing conditions on the derivative
Say we have a complex-valued function $f(z)$ which is holomorphic and consider the open unit disk to be the domain of the function. What conditions should the derivative $f'(z)$ satisfy for the function $f(z)$ to also be injective on the unit disk?
Is it even possible to just place conditions on $f'(z)$ and ensure injectivity for $f(z)$?

See here.

And this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3354390/42969
